# How to update my global variable value in C for data type Char *

Tags: c, global-variables

I have a global variable ->

```
static char *password = "superman";
```

and a local variable ->

```
const char *wifipsk = "batman";
```

How can I update my global variable password from superman to batman in C. Thank you.

Comment: Define them as arrays and not pointers to literals, then simply `strcpy`.

Comment: And make sure `password` is declared long enough to hold whatever you're copying.

Comment: You can also use `password = wifipsk`, but this will become invalid when you leave the scope that declares `wifipsk`.

Comment: @Barmar The string literal is static in the memory, so it should work. But I won't do that.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Good point, I was thinking that the local string was an array.

Comment: Imagine you have `static int password = 1234;` and `const int wifipsk = 42;`. How would you do it?

Comment: I tried using the modify() function which i normally use for integers. But it didnt work here.

Comment: @Nishith We have no idea what the `modify()` function is. [Edit] and show what you have tried. Then we can help. Read this: [ask] and this: [mcve]

Comment: @EugeneSh.. I cannot change the datatype because the "const char *wifipsk" is extracted from a data of json format and this value has to be updated to global variable.

Comment: @Jabberwocky. Sorry i meant the strcpy function.
void modify_y(char * wifipsk)
{
    strcpy(password, wifipsk);
}

Comment: @Barmar: `password = wifipsk` will incur a diagnostic, since `wifipsk` is `const char *`, and `password` does not have `const`.

Comment: Why is the global variable declared `char *` instead of `const char *`?

Comment: So `wifipsk` isn't actually initialized with a string literal, it comes from parsing JSON? That makes a big difference in the possible solutions.

Comment: Can you change the declaration  of `password` to an array, `char password[MAX_PASS_LEN];`?

Comment: Another option is `password = strdup(wifipsk);`

Comment: Your code in the question does not reflect your actual problem, so the solutions you are getting here might be not optimal or appropriate at all.

Comment: @Barmar. I cannot declare password to an array. The global variable was declared const  but i removed it. I thought const may cause issue while updating the global value so i removed it..

Answer (score 2):

This little piece of code contains much more trouble than you might possibly suspect!

At very first: You assign string literals to pointers to non-const. While legal as string literals are of type array of `char` (originating from times where `const` keyword simply did not yet exist and when introduced C designers opted for not breaking existing code) they are still immutable and writing to results in undefined behaviour. So you should always assign string literals only to pointers to const, never to anything else:

```
static char const* password = "superman";
```

If you want to exchange this password by other literals you can do so by simple assignment:

```
password = wifipsk;
```

I assume, though, that you want to be able to exchange the password by a string you retrieved during runtime, e.g. by user input.

Then quickly the question arises: How to manage the memory required for?

The most stable way is to store the password in an array instead:

```
static char password[256] = "superman"; // NOW non-const is valid
```

Now you can store passwords with length up to some reasonable limit (here: 255 characters + terminating null character).

Whenever you read or generate a new password (but make sure maximum password size is not exceeded!) you can just `memcpy` (if string length is already known anyway), `strcpy` (string length at least not exceeding the maximum) or `strncpy` (no guarantees at all) it into the static array. You could even read or generate into this password array directly, skipping the step of copying from an intermediate array (again: stay below size limit!) – *if* that's suitable for your use case (counter example: if you first want to validate a new password before and possibly reject it; then you don't want to lose the old password).

Answer (score 0):

`wifipsk` is assigned with reference to the string literal. String literals lifetime is the same as the program.

So you can safely assign, but your code will not ***const correct***

```
password = wifipsk;
```